# i want to make by python a script do this a*2/2*7*1443

Tags: python

```
a = input("enter resulte  : ")
b = int(a/2)
c = int(b*7)
d = int(c*1443)
print(d)
but give me this error
enter resulte  : 1'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 3, in <module>
    b = int(a/2)
```

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'

Comment: try `int(a)/2` instead

Comment: `input` returns a string. You need to convert to an integer, like `a = int(input("enter resulte  : "))`

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to divide a string rather than an integer.
The following code will work.

```
a = int(input("enter resulte  : "))
```

Comment: ok thank you it's work